Github blocks user from pushing, even after successful previous pushes
I am collaborating using github. I have a repository, and I've added my collaborators github accounts to that repository. They pulled a branch, made some changes, and pushed an update to that branch successfully.
A few days later, they tried to make another update to their branch, but when they hit push, they got an error message blocking the push telling them that they don't have permission to push. Nothing changed on github, so why is it now blocking them?!

Can you show the text of the error they received? It might help.

The error reads You don't have permissions to push to "/" on GitHub. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead?

Is is possible that the first push created a new branch name? I can envision a scenario where a branch protection rule is applying to all branches, so the first push would succeed because there's nothing to protect yet, but subsequent pushes would be blocked by the branch protection. (I don't know for sure if this is possible- just kind of brainstorming here...)

Thanks for the brainstorming - I created the branch before my collaborator joined, so I assume this isn't the problem, but I'll double check my branch protection rule is correctly hitting the branch in question (github's interface is kinda awful for that, imo)

Do you think it's possible the fact my collaborator is using library chromebook(s) is related? Their machine might be different from day to day.

In order to push, they need be authenticated. If they are switching machines, it's likely they aren't authenticated on the new machine the same way. So, yes, this is likely the culprit.

They're using VScode on github codespaces as their editor, is there a way to force a github authentication/login using VScode or the terminal? I looked at it myself and everything I can find on the window implies they're correctly logged into their correct github account

It sounds like a frustrating situation, there could be a few reasons why your collaborators are experiencing this issue. Try to Role Changes like Double-check that their roles haven't inadvertently changed. Sometimes, permissions can get altered without anyone realizing it. Also Repository Settings try to make sure the repository settings haven't been updated to restrict push access. Also SSH Keys If they're using SSH keys, confirm that their keys are still valid and haven't been revoked or changed. This can sometimes cause permission issues and Branch Protection Rules Check if there are any branch protection rules in place that might be preventing pushes to the branch

Tried all 4 of those places, everything looks correct to me;    - Looked at Roles: listed as "Collaborator";


Under Rules/Rulesets I have one Ruleset named "Open" which targets "All branches" and has all of the boxes under "Branch rules" unchecked;


I'm not using any SSH keys, nor is my collaborator;


I only have one Branch Protection Rule, and it applies to the "main" branch and not the one my collaborator is working on



Do you think it's possible the fact my collaborator is using library chromebook(s) is related? Their machine might be different from day to day.
